# Erro plugin wordpress, ou seja, campo em branco no array

Tags: array, wordpress, plugin, plugin-wordpress

boa noite!
Estou desenvolvendo um site para um restaurante e nele instalei um plugin de sistemas de reservas de mesa, chamado (https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/restaurant-reservations/)

Acontece o seguinte, quando subo o site pela hospedagem o campo horário, não funciona, ele fica em branco; mesmo reinstalando o plugin ele fica em branco, li no github do desenvolvedor que outros plugins podem afetar o horário **e eu gostaria de remover o horário**

O problema de remover é que eu mexi na parte do array

```
* See /includes/template-functions.php
     */
    $fields = array(

        // Reservation details fieldset
        'reservation'   => array(
            'legend'    => __( 'Preencha todos os campos', 'restaurant-reservations' ),
            'fields'    => array(
                'date'      => array(
                    'title'         => __( 'Data da reserva', 'restaurant-reservations' ),
                    'request_input' => empty( $request->request_date ) ? '' : $request->request_date,
                    'callback'      => 'rtb_print_form_text_field',
                    'required'      => true,
                ),
                'time'      => array(
                    'title'         => __( 'Horário da reserva', 'restaurant-reservations' ),
                    'request_input' => empty( $request->request_time ) ? '' : $request->request_time,
                    'callback'      => 'rtb_print_form_text_field',
                    'required'      => true,
                ),
                'party'     => array(
                    'title'         => __( 'Pessoas', 'restaurant-reservations' ),
                    'request_input' => empty( $request->party ) ? '' : $request->party,
                    'callback'      => 'rtb_print_form_select_field',
                    'callback_args' => array(
                        'options'   => $this->get_form_party_options(),
                    ),
                    'required'      => true,
                ),
            ),
        ),

        // Contact details fieldset
        'contact'   => array(
            'legend'    => __( 'Detalhes de Contato', 'restaurant-reservations' ),
            'fields'    => array(
                'name'      => array(
                    'title'         => __( 'Nome Completo', 'restaurant-reservations' ),
                    'request_input' => empty( $request->name ) ? '' : $request->name,
                    'callback'      => 'rtb_print_form_text_field',
                    'required'      => true,
                ),
                'email'     => array(
                    'title'         => __( 'Email Válido', 'restaurant-reservations' ),
                    'request_input' => empty( $request->email ) ? '' : $request->email,
                    'callback'      => 'rtb_print_form_text_field',
                    'callback_args' => array(
                        'input_type'    => 'email',
                    ),
                    'required'      => true,
                ),
                'phone'     => array(
                    'title'         => __( 'Telefone', 'restaurant-reservations' ),
                    'request_input' => empty( $request->phone ) ? '' : $request->phone,
                    'callback'      => 'rtb_print_form_text_field',
                    'callback_args' => array(
                        'input_type'    => 'tel',
                    ),
                ),
                'add-message'   => array(
                    'title'     => __( 'Adicionar Mensagem', 'restaurant-reservations' ),
                    'request_input' => '',
                    'callback'  => 'rtb_print_form_message_link',
                ),
                'message'       => array(
                    'title'         => __( 'Mensagem', 'restaurant-reservations' ),
                    'request_input' => empty( $request->message ) ? '' : $request->message,
                    'callback'      => 'rtb_print_form_textarea_field',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
```

removi, mas quando tento efetuar a solicitação o sistema pedi pra adicionar o horário, **como faço para corrigir isso** ?
Imagem com erro: http://prntscr.com/jtgc83

Este link, ele informa exatamente o meu problema, mas não consigo fazer isso, veja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá!
Entrei em contato com o desenvolvedor do plugin e ele mesmo ajudou a resolver o problema. Ele diz:

> Hi Demetrius,
>   The following is a tiny little plugin that will hide the time field in the booking form (all bookings will be set for 12pm):
>   https://gist.github.com/NateWr/9068c5d12ef458eb40ca
>   To use it, click the Download button at the top, unpack the .zip file, and upload the .php file to your /wp-content/plugins/ directory. You can then activate it from the Plugins screen in your WordPress admin area.

Ele diz que para ocultar o horário, precisa baixar o *.php e adicionar ele no diretório /wp-content/plugins/* e assim ativá-lo.

Obrigado pela ajuda Felipe!
Problema resolvido!

Comment: Sucesso! era este link mesmo que eu tinha visto hahaha

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu entendi você quer remover o horário. Achei [aqui](https://gist.github.com/NateWr/9068c5d12ef458eb40ca) na documentação dele o seguinte:

```
// Adicionar no seu functions.php
add_filter( 'rtb_booking_form_fields', 'rtbht_hide_time', 10, 2 );
function rtbht_hide_time( $fields, $request ) {
    $fields['reservation']['fields']['time']['callback'] = function() {
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="rtb-time" value="12:00 PM">';
    };
    return $fields;
}
```

Acredito que vc tenha que instalar novamente o plugin e adicionar isto no seu functions.php que deve resolver.

Comment: Olá, eu vou testar e caso dê certo eu retorno...